# Vectorizing with outer loop

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

How do I vectorize a  constructed R function so that sequences can be calculated?

The original function is:

```
A = function(j,x){
  if(x<0 & x>j){stop(print(1))}
  else{
    s=0
    for(k in 0:x){
      s = s + ((j-1) * ((2)^k) * x)
    }
  }
return(s)
}
```

and I want to add an outer loop that lets me run A(j, x) as a vector, where j = 3 and x = seq(-2:2)

Comment: Maybe `mapply` is what you're after?

Comment: You want to enhance the function to be able to process a vector only for `x`, or also for `j`?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to vectorize a function in R is `Vectorize`. Note that the resulting function might not be very efficient.

```
Av <- Vectorize(A, vectorize.args = "x")

Av(j = 3, x = seq(-2, 2))
# [1] -7 -3  0  6 28
```

Comment: Not exactly the method I was looking for, but I managed to figure out how to put the function in an outer loop. Thanks though